# asp.net mvc 4 Controller within a contoller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Can I have a controller within a controller.

I already have a users controller and I now want to add a Roles controller, But i want to access the roles controller from within the users controller like so: /users/roles/index   rather than creating another controller and accessing it via /roles/index

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep to a typical REST implementation then I would suggest avoiding that and assign a controller to each of your root models (users, roles etc.).

Alternatively, if you want the Roles to be accesible only through the user, as a nested resource (meaning that you want to show, update, delete only roles of a particular user) then you can define routes like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "RolesForUser", // Route name
   "user/{userId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
   new { controller = "roles", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

So a link to `user/3/roles/index` will take you to the Index action of the Roles controller, for user 3.

If instead your intention is to hide the roles management behind a `/user/` url then I would go a bit further and create an user (or admin) `Area` in your MVC project (this is as simple as right-clicking on the project in Visual Studio and selecting `Add -> Area...`)